# Weights not changing while training on Inception V3 but working fine on VGG16

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train inception V3 for a binary classification and there seems to be something wrong. I'm using Keras for the implementation. The code is shown below:

```
def Inception():

    model = inception_v3.InceptionV3(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
                  input_shape=(imageheight, imagewidth, 3))
    x = model.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dense(1, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
    model = Model(input=model.input, output=x)

    # print(model.summary())

    return model
```

I have tried to initialise the weights with different values and even tried different optimizers:

```
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr = 5e-5, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
```

for everything, the output I'm getting is:

```
Epoch 1/100
611/611 [==============================] - 14s 23ms/step - loss: 11.5589 - acc: 0.2750 - val_loss: 11.5660 - val_acc: 0.2745
Epoch 2/100
611/611 [==============================] - 6s 9ms/step - loss: 11.5589 - acc: 0.2750 - val_loss: 11.5660 - val_acc: 0.2745
Epoch 3/100
611/611 [==============================] - 6s 9ms/step - loss: 11.5589 - acc: 0.2750 - val_loss: 11.5660 - val_acc: 0.2745
Epoch 4/100
611/611 [==============================] - 6s 9ms/step - loss: 11.5589 - acc: 0.2750 - val_loss: 11.5660 - val_acc: 0.2745
```

The weird thing is when I use the same dataset on VGG16, it works. The only this is I wrote the architecture for VGG16 from scratch.

So what should I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `activation='sigmoid'` for binary classification instead of `softmax`.